# Iterate through list to create new list with IDs Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So I am trying to use the IMDBpy module to connect a list of programs to their respective Genres. First I am trying to get a new list of their IMDB IDs to, from there, get their corresponding Genre.
Unfortunately I am unable to iterate through my list of programs and generate a new list of corresponding IDs. Somehow my function gets stuck at the first iteration. What am I missing in my definition?

```
from imdb import IMDB
ia = IMDb()
programs = ['midsomer murders', 'wheeler dealers: dream car', 'solo: a star wars story (2018)']
def ids_list(x):
    ids = []
    for item in list(x):
        movie = ia.search_movie(item)[0].getID()
        for movie in movies:
            ids.append(movie)
        return ids
    
ids_list(programs)
```

output:

```
['0118401']
```

As you can see only the first item comes through, whereas my code suggests it should append every item in the list after running it through `ia.search_movie(item)[0].getID()`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: move the `return ids` to out of the `outer-for-loop` n try

Comment: i mean just `un-indent` the `return` statement once

Comment: Yes just done that, now I get an IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: that would be on this line - `ia.search_movie(item)[0]`   -  sometimes you might not be getting any elements , so when you try to access `0-th` element it throws error

Comment: use `if len(ia.search_movie(item)):`  like so before that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return is indented incorrectly.  It returns after the first iteration of the for loop:

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
programs = ['midsomer murders', 'wheeler dealers: dream car', 'solo: a star wars story (2018)']
def ids_list(x):
    ids = []
    for item in list(x):
        movie = ia.search_movie(item)
        if movie:
          ids.append(movie[0].getID())
        else:
          ids.append(None)
    return ids
    
print(ids_list(programs))
```

shortened version using list comprehension and assignment operator (Python 3.8+):

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
programs = ['midsomer murders', 'wheeler dealers: dream car', 'solo: a star wars story (2018)']
def ids_list(x):
    return [m[0].getID() if (m:=ia.search_movie(i)) else None for i in x]
    
print(ids_list(programs))
```

Comment: Again syntax error in your code in (m:=ia.search_movie(i))

Comment: shortened version requires python 3.8+.  I'm guessing you are using an older version.  You can use the top version

Comment: Yes true I am, the top version is also giving me 
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes I think it has to do with the search movie value not being a string.

Comment: That would be a problem with the programs list, containing data you haven't shown.  You should check the output in list programs.  You could cast it to a string, but the real problem is your original list is malformed and needs to be fixed and the reason you are getting something other than strings found.

Comment: also, are you sure you only want the first movie's ID found and not all the possible IDs found?

Comment: Correct, there is some of my data in my original list that is causing the error, Im debugging this now. And yes, I think the first match of possible IDs should be sufficient. In general the titles seem to match the search_movie results quite well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I mean change your `for-loop` code to this :

```
for item in list(x):
    if len(ia.search_movie(item)):
        movies = ia.search_movie(item)[0].getID()
        [ids.append(movie) for movie in movies]
return ids
```